Python generator implementation is not reducing memory consumption
I have three json.gz files. Those three files contains different data (restaurants, menus and matchings) grouped by different Ids. I must read all of them and create new json files by Id with the respective data from those three files. I have one virtual machine and I have some memory restrictions when running my code.
At the begining, I consolidated these three files in three json objects and then I iterated them with a normal for-loop. With this solution, my code is consuming a lot of memory from my VM because I am loading the whole data.
I realized I need only the data for a particular Id to create the final json file and I should not load all the data for all Ids at the same time. Therefore, I though Python generator would be the solution in this case. I created the following code:
from json import loads

def load_data_set(string_restaurants_data: str,
                  string_menus_data: str,
                  string_matchings_data: str,): 


  menus_data = loads(string_menus_data)   
  matchings_data = loads(string_matchings_data)   
  restaurants_data = loads(string_restaurants_data)
  
  for id, menu_data in menus_data.items():
    yield id, restaurants_data[id], menu_data, matchings_data[id] if id in matchings_data else "{}"



def main():
    '''
    some code to read the json.gz files. The data is stored in these three string variables: string_restaurants_data, string_menus_data and string_matchings_data
    '''

    restaurants_data_set = load_data_set(string_restaurants_data,
                                             string_menus_data,
                                             string_matchings_data)
    
    size_generator = sys.getsizeof(restaurants_data_set)

    del string_menus_data
    del string_restaurants_data
    del string_matchings_data
    gc.collect()

    list_result = {}
    for restaurant in restaurants_data_set:
      result_data = aggregate_menu_data(restaurant[0],
                                        dumps(restaurant[2]),
                                        dumps(restaurant[1]),
                                        dumps(restaurant[3]),
                                        string_parameters,
                                        eval(debug))
    

      list_result.update(result_data)
    
    data['result'] = dumps(list_result)
     

I checked the Task Manager in the VM and I have not seen an important reduction in the memory consumption comparing the previous version without generators. Could anyone let me know if I implemented correctly the python generator to solve my need? or is there a better way to load only in memory the data I need to create a json file without affecting the speed?
Python version: 3.11

We don't know what to compare this version of the code to.

In any case, json.loads loads the whole object into memory. Creating a generator afterwards doesn't avoid that.

@mkrieger1 You are right. I missed this step. Is there any way to read only the data of one id in memory from these three files without loading all?.

Try ijson

No, your generator won't be doing anything here, since you've already loaded the 3 dicts. Since you are building up restaurants_data_set out of 3 separate files, a generator won't really help in this case.
Is there any reason why you can't just use a database? It's built for this type of stuff and is way more efficient.

First off, don't read the files into strings and parse them with json.loads, since you end up both the full string and dict in memory. Use json.load(f) on the file object to bypass this first step.
Then if you handle the files separately and just build up the result as you go along, you can avoid loading more than one into memory at any one point.
restaurants_data_set = {}
with open(string_menus_path, 'r') as f:
    for id, menu_data in json.load(f).items():
        restaurants_data_set[id] = [None, menu_data '"{}"']
with open(string_restaurants_path, 'r') as f:
    for id, restaurant_data in json.load(f).items():
        restaurants_data_set[id][0] = restaurant_data
with open(string_matchings_path, 'r') as f:
    for id, matchings_data in json.load(f).items():
        restaurants_data_set[id][2] = matchings_data

for id, (restaurant_data, menu_data, matchings_data) in restaurants_data_set.items():
    ...

For something more advanced, you could have a go at reading the json data in chunks.
